# devise update attribute after sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to update an attribute for the `current_user` after signing out with devise.

If I use `after_sign_out_path_for(resource)` the current_user is nil.

When I use `Warden::Manager.before_logout` works fine just when there is an user signed in.

I have problems with this because I have an API and a client in the same application (client creates, updates, delete, etc through the API)

Is there another way to do it? Maybe a custom action?

Comment: Do you need this update to be done immediately after logout or after a while?

Comment: before or after logout. It means when the user is logged in `user.some_attribute` has some value and  when is logged out `user.some_attribute` has another value.

Comment: This worked in devise 3.2, but no longer in 3.4. Nothing in the change log about it, might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.

Store the user id in a cookie.

In the `after_sign_out_path_for(resource)` method, find the user object from this cookie and change the attribute.

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  user = User.find(cookies[:user_id])
  user.update_attributes(some_attribute: false)
  root_path
end
```